# Why should you not use setXXXSize()?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Whenever I look for solutions related to layouts, I come across people who advise against using the `setMinimumSize()`, `setPreferredSize()` and `setMaximumSize()` methods.

The typical argument is, that a correct `LayoutManager` should be used instead.

My understanding is that the `LayoutManager` calculates the real width/height of the components, by looking for how much space they need in order to be resized correctly. So using the 3 methods looks reasonable to me - for example when you want a component to have only a certain size and let another component always take the rest.

So why is using `setXXXSize()` so discouraged?

Comment: _for example when you want a component to have only a certain size and let another component always take the rest_ that's the exact task of the LayoutManager, not of the component (the latter can't know its surroundings). All a component itself can know are its own requirements. The other way round, the component itself is the _only_ one which has enough knowledge to advertise/calculate its own size requirements, there's nothing that client code can do to infere those requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of good answers on the linked duplicate ([Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)).

Adding to the reasons why: With few exceptions, if you are using these methods you are probably fine-tuning your GUI to look good on a specific look-and-feel (and with your system-specific settings, e.g. your preferred desktop font, etc.). The methods themselves aren't inherently evil, but the typical reasons for using them *are*. As soon as you start tuning pixel positions and sizes in a layout you run the risk of your GUI breaking (or at minimum, looking bad), on other platforms.

As an example of this, try changing your application's default look-and-feel. Even just with the options available on your platform, you will no doubt be surprised at how poorly the results can be rendered.

So, in the name of keeping your GUI functional and nice-looking on all platforms (remember, one of the major benefits of Java is its cross-platformness), you should rely on layout managers, etc., to automatically adjust the sizes of your components so that it renders correctly outside of your specific development environment.

All that said, you can certainly conceive of situations where these methods are justified. Again, they aren't inherently evil, just make sure you are aware of the high potential for complications when you use them, and always try and think if there is another look-and-feel-independent solution to your problems.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually much more understandable than the accepted solution of the linked post. I think I get it now what they mean by "proper LayoutManager".

Comment: +1 for a much better (and more objective) answer than the subjective accepted answer in the link.

Comment: @AyCe If you find yourself getting frustrated with standard layout managers, there are a lot of good free, open-source third-party ones, for example [JGoodies' `FormLayout`](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/), or [`MigLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/). In fact, Eclipse's WindowBuilder GUI editor ships with support for these layout managers.

Comment: I never understood why I would need external JARs for some simple apps. Java's built-in LayoutManagers are just fine, but thanks. :)

Comment: @AyCe _Java's built-in LayoutManagers are just fine_ actually, they aren't, at least not without a way too steep learning curve and even after mastering that climb none of them gets you completely what you need in everyday layout.

Comment: @kleopatra  I disagree.  I haven't met a layout yet in 10+ years that I couldn't whip up in short order, by hand, using the standard LMs, and we get some crazy requirements.

Comment: Whether a given layout manager is or isn't "fine" of course depends entirely on the situation. If you're trying to lay out components in a single row or column, for example, there's nothing "not fine" about a `BoxLayout`. The real point is this: *Some* times I see setXXX being used because for one reason or another the coder either couldn't get layout managers to produce the desired results, or simply felt that using them was too cumbersome. So, I bring up the existence of other layout managers simply as an option to file away if that *happens* to be the fundamental issue in a given situation.

Comment: @splungebob nothing new (and nothing bad) in you disagreeing :-) At the end of the day the _choice_ of LayoutManager boils down to a taste issue- can't resist: some don't know all the tasted available <grin>. As long as we let the manager do its tasks without interfering, all is just fine.